# How can I fake a Class used insite SUT using FakeItEasy

Tags: fakeiteasy

Am having a little trouble understanding what and what cannot be done using FakeItEasy. Suppose I have a class

```
public class ToBeTested{

   public bool MethodToBeTested(){
      SomeDependentClass dependentClass = new SomeDependentClass();
      var result = dependentClass.DoSomething();
      if(result) return "Something was true";
      return "Something was false";
   }
 }
```

And I do something like below to fake the dependent class

```
 var fakedDepClass = A.Fake<DependentClass>();
 A.CallTo(fakedDepClass).WithReturnType<bool>().Returns(true);
```

How can i use this fakedDepClass when am testing MethodToBeTested. If DependentClass was passed as argument, then I can pass my fakedDepClass, but in my case it is not (also this is legacy code that I dont control).

Any ideas?

Thanks
K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `new SomeDependentClass()` inside `MethodToBeTested` means that you get a concrete actual `SomeDependentClass` instance. It's not a fake, and cannot be a FakeItEasy fake.

You have to be able to inject the fake class into the code to be tested, either (as you say) via an argument to `MethodToBeTested` or perhaps through one of `ToBeTested`'s constructors or properties.

If you can't do that, FakeItEasy will not be able to help you.

If you do not have the ability to change `ToBeTested` (and I'd ask why you're writing tests for it, but that's an aside), you may need to go with another isolation framework. I have used [TypeMock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) for just the sort of situation you describe, and it did a good job.

Comment: Like I said before, am trying to write some tests around legacy code, I dont have the luxury of changing the SUT's. I did take a look at TypeMock and it does give me the ability to Fake all instances of a particular class (I tested it and it works just fine). Thanks for your response.

Comment: @KarthikBalasubramanian why can't you change the legacy code?

Comment: legacy code is in production being used by a ton of other applications. Currently there are no tests written against it.